# autonomy_create driver yaw angle range is [2pi ~ -2pi]?

Tags: navigation, robot-localization, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I want to compare my odometry yaw angle and imu yaw angle to understand current accuracy of my IMU.
From what I get, IMU output is [pi ~ -pi] but the autonomy_create (using irobotcreate2) yaw angle output starts from 0 upto +/-2pi depending on the robot turning clockwise or anti-clockwise. is this correct?

If I can confirm autonomy_create output as [2pi ~ -2pi] I think need to change the source to match with my IMU output. I intend to run robot_localization and robot_pose_ekf in the future, but I think difference in yaw output range of my odom yaw angle and imu yaw angle will have some problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272539/autonomy_create-driver-yaw-angle-range-is-%5B2pi-%7E--2pi%5D?/) by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rotations are represented as quaternions in ROS, so, for example, -pi/2 will have the same representation as 3*pi/2. As long as they are right-handed (yaw increases counter-clockwise), and they both have the same zero point, you should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0